# Why widgets declared later appear first?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Python's `tkinter` library to create a small GUI. The code of the app is as follows :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
APP_TITLE = "HiDE"

class Application(tk.Frame):
    """This class establishes an entity for the application"""
    #The constructor of this class
    def __init__(self, master=None):        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()

    def setupWidgets(self):
        self.message = tk.Label(self,text='Login')
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self,text='Quit',command=self.quit)
        self.logButton = tk.Button(self,text='Login',command=self.quit)
        self.master.title(APP_TITLE)
        self.master.minsize("300","300")
        self.master.maxsize("300","300")
        self.message.grid()
        self.logButton.grid()
        self.quitButton.grid()

#Setting up the application
app = Application()
img = tk.PhotoImage(file='icon.png')
#getting screen parameters
w = h = 300#max size of the window
ws = app.master.winfo_screenwidth() #This value is the width of the screen
hs = app.master.winfo_screenheight() #This is the height of the screen

# calculate position x, y
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
#This is responsible for setting the dimensions of the screen and where it is placed
app.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
app.master.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', app.master._w, img)
app.master.i_con = tk.Label(app.master, image=img)
app.master.i_con.grid()
app.setupWidgets()  #<-- This is the function call
app.mainloop()
```

The `setupWidgets` function is called after the image is set up, but the output is :

[image: The output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time you grid the Label with the image, you have already called grid on the Frame in your class. This class is where the other widgets are placed in, so it's placed above the Label with the image.

Instead of

```
app.master.i_con = tk.Label(app.master, image=img)
```

try

```
app.master.i_con = tk.Label(app, image=img)
```

to put the Label with the image in the Frame with the other widgets.

---

On a side note, calling grid without specifying a row and column doesn't really make sense.

Comment: i hadn't really started positioning the widgets before I saw this. That's why there were no rows and cols..